# How to acces individual solutions of outputs in maple

Tags: maple

I am trying to get to specific solutions from the output in maple. Sometimes there are multiple solutions and they come as tuples. If I assign a variable to the output, I would like to do something like `x(1)` gives me the first solution, `x(2)` gives me the second solution and so on.

```
with(LinearAlgebra):
with(VectorCalculus):

A := Matrix([[1, 2], [8, 1]])
x := Eigenvectors(A)
```

The eigenvectors `x` are:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using round brackets, use square brackets to denote the index position for the element you wish to return in the expression sequence. For example:

```
x[1];
x[2];
```

Returns:

```
Vector([-3, 5])
Matrix([[-1/2, 1/2], [1, 1]])
```

For more on indexing data structures in Maple, the [8th chapter in the user manual](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=UserManual%2FChapter08) may come in handy.

Comment: Thanks. The subscript x_1 could also be used.

Answer (score 2):

The `Eigenvectors` command returns a sequence of two things.

So you could also use multiple assignment, to assign each to its own name directly. Eg,

```
with(LinearAlgebra):
with(VectorCalculus):

A := Matrix([[1, 2], [8, 1]]):

xvals, xvecs := Eigenvectors(A);

                        [-3]  [-1/2    1/2]
        xvals, xvecs := [  ], [           ]
                        [ 5]  [ 1       1 ]

xvals;

                       [-3]
                       [  ]
                       [ 5]

xvecs;

                   [-1/2    1/2]
                   [           ]
                   [ 1       1 ]
```